# How to prevent div with position:relative to allocate extra space

Tags: css, html

[Here is jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MybuG/)

Here is the code..

```
 <div id="xxx1"> 
     <div class="xxx1">
            txt
    </div> </div>
```

And CSS

```
#xxx1{
    border:1px solid black;
    min-height:25px;

}
.xxx1{
    border:1px solid green;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
}
```

I want to remove extra space from div id "xxx1". How to do that? And I cannot use fixed height cause I want that div to increase its height if I want to add some more data inside that div.

[Here is jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MybuG/)

Comment: +1 for giving fiddle link.

Comment: What is that extra space in `id=xxx1`?
You should be more spesific Is that the effect you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/7UJjM/

Answer (score 2):

Provided I understood the question, get rid of `padding` on `body`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EvuF/)

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

You may also find `box-sizing:border-box` useful which integrates `border` and `padding` into `width` and `height`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZxtt/)

```
#xxx1{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.xxx1{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### Edit

RE: no.. I want to remove blank space inside div id "xxx1".

Well you can do that in a variety of ways, the right way would depend on what the context is. Here are a couple:

- Position .xxx1 using `position:absolute` so it's taken out of the flow of the page. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaVSW/)
- Set `height:0px` and set it with JavaScript when you add content to it.

Comment: no.. I want to remove blank space inside div id "xxx1". I have set position of div class "xxx1" to relative and top: -50px. But div with "xxx1" class is still holding its space inside div id "xxx1". I want to remove that space.

Answer (score 0):

Here try to change it like this

```
.xxx1{
border:1px solid green;
height:auto;
position:relative;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you cant remove the spacing added by relative positioning.**  setting the padding and margin on the body wont do it.  setting the box-sizing wont do it.  setting the font size to 0 wont do it.  doing something with javascript is just silly.

You have these options:

1. make the next item have a negative margin (ick).
2. float the item, tho this wont allow overlapping (if you need that)
3. **set the outer div to a relative position and the item you want to move to absolute position (and set the top (or bottom) and left (or right) values.  this positions the item you want to move according to its outer div (not the window).**

Number 3 is almost always the best way to go.  Think about how the page will change with variable content to make sure you choose the right option (and correct corner to position from).

If the outer div that you set to a relative position is not adjusted in space (using top/bottom/left/right), then that div does not have any extra unwanted space.  If you need to adjust the outer div AND the inner div, set all moving divs as absolute, and the closest parent as relative;  the movement (top/bottom/right/left) will be based on that relative parent.